# Need to render after the function is executed React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to fetch some data from API gateway and use that to render a tree but i'm not able to do so.
Here is what i am trying

```
var structure = [

];

export default function App() {
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await axios.get(`Some API_GATEWAY Request`)
      structure.push(JSON.parse(res['data']))
      console.log(structure[0])
    }
    
    fetchData();
    console.log(structure[0])
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(structure[0])}
      <Tree data={structure} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the output is

```
undefined //from 3rd console.log
undefined //from 2nd console.log
some value //from 1st console.log
```

how to get the value inside the return so that i can use the strucutre

Comment: `fetchData().then(() => { console.log(structure[0]); })` will show `some value` and to have it rendered you need a reference. Basically `fetchData` is asynchronous but you are accessing `structure[0]` *before* it gets populated which is ... asynchronously.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi  can you please show how to render it

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi can you show some example on how to render it using reference I have never used it

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-react-refs/

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [catties, setCatties] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchCats = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await axios.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search");
    setLoading(false);
    setCatties([...catties, ...res.data]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCats();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h1> ...loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {catties.map(el => (
        <img src={el.url} alt="Catty" key={el.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Run this code in codesandbox, you will see how it works. This is a standrat clean way of doing this. Usually you want to keep these kind of functions inside of redux or context. Please let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can do:

1. make structure array a part of your state:
2. You can create that function above useEffect, and call it inside. So code will look like this:

```
 export default function App() {
       const [structure, setStructure] = React.useState([]);
       async function fetchData() {
           const res = await axios.get(`Some API_GATEWAY Request`)
           setStructure(JSON.parse(res['data']))
            console.log(structure[0])
       }                
          React.useEffect(() => {    
            fetchData();
          }, []);            
          return (
            <div className="App">
              {console.log(structure[0])}
              <Tree data={structure} />
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but it never executed the fetchData function

Comment: can you please provide your api which you are trying to call? I will try too and send back the result

Comment: sorry but i can't provide you that  API